# Trying to read a string into a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm pretty new with C++, so bear with me. I'm trying to read a file very fast into a 2D vector.

When compiling I'm getting the error `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::read(std::basic_string&, char&)'`. I tried casting it with reinterpret but it didn't work either.

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > data(ROWS, std::vector<std::string>(COLUMNS));

...

reader.read(data[row][column], strlen); <-- compilation chokes here
```

I'm reading the file in binary mode, so I'm not certain I can use `>>` because I think it returns formatted output.

Comment: just do `reader >> data[row][column];`

Comment: FYI reading a file 'very fast' in C++ means reading it in all at once and then parsing it in memory.

Comment: Also *very fast* might imply things like limiting the number of memory allocations, using contiguous memory... (i.e. `std::vector<std::string>` and map `(row,col)->index`). The input format is not described, but if you want it *really* fast you may want to avoid iostreams, read the file in blocks and interpret the data manually... then again *very fast* is probably a relative term here....

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What's another way to read a file without iostream?

Comment: `open`, `read`, `close`; `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose`; `mmap`.... probably some platform specific ways. If performance really matters, then measure different alternatives and choose the best you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[basic_istream::read()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) accepts a char* argument, not an std::string.

If I follow the [example code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read#Example):

```c
std::string &str = data[row][column];
str.resize(strlen, ' ');
reader.read(&*str.begin(), strlen);
```

Comment: c_str() is const char*, you should not change it. Nothing guarantees that the pointer points to the internal buffer.

Comment: I tried using `reader.read(reinterpret_cast<std::string>(data[row][column], strlen);` but it didn't work either :/

Comment: Thanks for the fast and correct answer! Do you know why I need to use `str.resize(strlen, ' ');`?

Comment: It's to allocate the area in memory where read() is going to put the data. You need it to be at least strlen bytes long since this is the amount of data you're putting there.